# How can I shorten routes in Codeigniter for certain requests?

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have a page that has this category URL website.com/category/view/honda-red-car and I just want it to say http://website.com/honda-red-car no html or php and get rid of the category view in the URL.. this website has been done using the CodeIgniter framework..

also this product view URL website.com/product/details/13/honda-accord-red-car
and I want it to be website.com/honda-accord-red-car PLEASE HELP!!!

I cannot find correct instructions on what I am doing wrong??

Comment: sorry no http:// not enough reputation ;(

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into the [URI Routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) part of the user guide.

If you have concrete set of urls that you want to route then by adding rules to the `application/config/routes.php` you should be able to achieve what you want.

If you want some general solution (any uri segment can be a `product/details` page) then you might need to add every other url explicitly to the `routes.php` config file and set up a catch-all rule to route everything else to the right controller/method. Remember to handle 404 urls too!

**Examples:**
Lets say the `/honda-red-car` is something special and you want only this one to be redirected internally you write:

```
$routes['honda-red-car'] = 'product/details/13/honda-accord-red-car';
```

If you want to generalize everything that starts with the `honda-` string you do:

```
$routes['(honda-.*)'] = 'product/details_by_slug/$1'; // imaginary endpoint
```

These rules are used inside a `preg_replace()` call passing in the key as the pattern, and the value as the replace string, so the `()` are for capture groups, `$1` for placing the capture part.

Be careful with the patterns, if they are too general they might catch every request coming in, so:

```
$routes['(.*)'] = 'product/details_by_slug/$1';
```

While it would certainly work for any car name like `suzuki-swift-car` too it would catch the ordinary root url, or the `product/details/42` request too.

These rules are evaulated top to bottom, so start with specific rules at the top and leave general rules at the end of the file.

Comment: I have been staring at this page for a very long time I still am not understanding? It tells you what needs to be done just not too clear? Is their anyway you can provide me an example of 1?

Comment: can I not just do the http://www.website.com/product? do I have to have a controller? or can I pass the controller and go straight to the chosen url

Comment: You can map arbitrary paths on the left (the array key) to arbitrary controller/method on the right (the array value). Not sure if I'm getting your question.

Answer (score 2):

In Routes.php you need to create one like so

`$route['mycar'] = "controller_name/function_name";`

So for your example it would be:

`$route['honda-red-car] = "category/view/honda-red-car";`